# Doxygen crashing during parsing

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to use Doxygen to generate documentation from the source code.
I'm calling doxygen from a specific folder from the command line, like this:

doxygen doxygen_config

doxygen_config file is almost entirely the same as the default created by Doxygen, I only made some minor changes, as follow:

```
INPUT = ./../../src/*.c
SUBFOLDER = YES
OUTPUT = ../../doc/
```

(I have tried with absolut paths, same result)
When I execute this command I can see Doxygen parsing the files:

```
The message during parsing is like this:
Searching for include files...
Searching for example files...
Searching for images...
Searching for dot files...
Searching for msc files...
Searching for dia files...
Searching for files to exclude
Searching INPUT for files to process...
Searching for files in directory C:/Users/workspace-cpp/project/src
Searching for files in directory C:/Users/workspace-cpp/project/src/s1
Searching for files in directory C:/Users/workspace-cpp/project/src/s2
Reading and parsing tag files
Parsing files
Preprocessing C:/Users/workspace-cpp/project/src/s1/s1.c...
Parsing file C:/Users/workspace-cpp/project/src/s1/s1.c...
Preprocessing C:/Users/workspace-cpp/project/src/s2/s2.c...
Parsing file C:/Users/workspace-cpp/project/src/s1/s1.c...
.
.
.
Computing dependencies between directories...
Generating citations page...
Counting data structures...
Resolving user defined references...
Finding anchors and sections in the documentation...
Transferring function references...
Combining using relations...
Adding members to index pages...
```

And then it crashes. I receive a popup from windows with the message "doxygen.exe stopped working" (APPCRASH)
If I go to the OUTPUT folder, I can see Doxygen created some folders: latex (empty) and html (only tabs.css inside it).

Any idea what may  be causing this?

Comment: Which version are you using? When not the latest 1.8.11 please try this version. Please also check whether or not your disk (one of your disks) is nearly full. In case the problem persists please attach a (small)_ self contained example in zip format that shows the problem (or create  a bug report on bugzilla).

Comment: I've got more than 100gb of free space in my hard drive. Doxygen was downloaded today (version 1.8.11). I've made a small example of this: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxPQVucbGL-QUUwyN1pxNjZsWWM). Just type "doxygen dox_file" in the command prompt from inside the folder. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I found a workaround that will work for now. I downloaded the windows binary version 1.7.6.1. Hope someone have an answer for the problem though.

Comment: I downloaded the rar file and extracted the files and ran doxygen, all went OK, no crash whatsoever.