# How to use doxygen to create documentation for my config file in my project repository on Windows?

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I have been working on my project and have done the documentation using the doxygen. Now I want to run the doxygen using the [doxygen doxygen.config] command on the windows terminal, but it says that the doxygen command is not found. I been used to using it in Linux and it seems to be so easy. I tried using doxygen wizard to generate the doxygen but it does not seem to work. Can someone tell me how to approach this issue?

I run the wizard with the doxygen file and it generates the "generated" folder in which there is the "html" and "later" folder. But there is nothing in the html folder.

Comment: i see that there is a similar issue on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458985/doxygen-crashing-during-parsing.

Comment: guys, best is to downgrade to an older version. Use the 1.7.6.1 version. Hope someone figures out why the latest version has a BUG!!!!!!!!.

Comment: Downgrading is only a short term solution. We can only fix problems that can be reproduced, so please show how that is done by creating a self-contained example showing the problem and attach that to a bug report (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=doxygen).

Comment: What version are you presently running?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like it is a bug that would be best reported on the bug-tracker.